# How to extract specific value from spark dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to extract count using sql query from pyspark. count is in spark dataframe i want to use the count value to use in if condition but not able to extract the value. how can i extract the int value from spark dataframe

```
 query = "select count(*) as count from abc where FLAG= 'C' "
    counter = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample", driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                                           query=query, user="root", password="root").load()

if counter['count']>0:
   print('hello')
else:
   print('hi')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like below. collect the value from data frame

```
max_date = counter.collect()[0][0]
```